# Encrypted an protected data for qlikview to consume

Tags: qlikview

Have a lot of data in a database which I want different qlikview implementations to be able to consume.

The data in the MS-SQL database is for several customers and I do not want to let them in directly in the db. I want to have an API where the customer can get their data over SSL and password protection.

At the same time I want it to be as easy as it can be for the customer to consume the data within their qlikview program.

What would be the best solution for us to build so that the custoemr easily can consume our data from our database and where the data i encrypted en protected?

/Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do that. One solution could be access over https.

You set up a webserver with a simple webappkicaton. The app returns a html table containing only the customers data. Authentiction (Ssl) can be done in a secure way by passwort or TLS.

Authorisation can be handled either in the webserver or in the application.

Importing records from a html table works very well in QlikView, but ist depends a little bit on the size.

HTH